# What component is represented by reference designator GT?

Tags: pcb, identification, circuit-protection

[image]

I can see that G represents a generator/oscillator, and T represents a Transformer, but what does GT represent?

Comment: An oscillating transformer?: I can see that you can't see that we can't see what you're talking about without some more information.  How about editing your question so we won't have to    guess/close your question?

Comment: It could be something like a gas discharge tube, but it's hard to guess. Do you have a picture of the component?

Comment: "Gas Tube" -- it's an overvoltage protection device.

Comment: Designators can be somewhat arbitary. There are conventions for the common stuff but when one has an unusual component a designer will often end up making it up as they go along.

Comment: @Roy If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

As I guessed in my comment, it's a Gas Discharge Tube. As Dave Tweed says, it's an overvoltage protection device, or more precisely, it protects against high voltage *spikes* as opposed to long term faults.

Here's an excerpt from a [Littlefuse datasheet](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/gas_discharge_tubes/littelfuse_gdt_cg_cg2_datasheet.pdf.pdf):

> GDTs function as switches which dissipate a
>   minimum amount of energy and therefore handle
>   currents that far surpass other types of transient
>   voltage protection. Their gas-filled, rugged ceramic
>   metal construction make them well suited to adverse
>   environments.

Comment: is there any device the protects against long-term faults?

Comment: @Jasen For long term overvoltage protection, you typically need a circuit, rather than a single device. Though, depending on the applicaion, a PTC can sometimes be used.